# jQuery add rows dynamically with unique input field ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to add dynamic rows (max up to 6): But it adds 2 rows at a time for some reason. So this is the order. By default 1 row is displayed, once AddPO is clicked, it inserts 2 rows, again 2 rows on button click and then ofcourse 1 since it checks for max 6 rows.

Why is it not inserting one row at a time?

Here is the code:

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#addPO').click(addPO)
});   

    var current = 1;
    function addPO() {
      current++;
        if (current < 7){
        var strToAdd = '<p><input id="FinalPONumber'+current+'" name="FinalPONumber'+current+'" size="20" /> <input id="FinalPOAmount'+current+'" name="FinalPOAmount'+current+'" size="20" /><input type="file" id="FinalPOFile'+current+'" name="FinalPOFile'+current+'"/></p>'

        $('#mainField').append(strToAdd)
        }
    }

 </script>


 html:



 <div id="mainField">
        <p>
      <input type="text" id="FinalPONumber1" name="FinalPONumber1" size="20" /> 
      <input type="text" id="FinalPOAmount1" name="FinalPOAmount1" size="20" />
      <input type="file" id="FinalPOFile1" name="FinalPOFile1"/>
        </p>
   </div>

   <p>
    <input type="button" id="addPO" value="Add Final PO">
```

Comment: seems fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7tKtk/1/

Comment: my html code is inside a loop and thats where it adds 2 rows at a time. JSFiddle works fine. Although I don't think its a looping issue, because it adds 2 rows without looping

Comment: then you need to share that code